# Typescript - DIfferent types for creating and editing

Tags: typescript

I have the following Type that defines an User:

```
type UserType = {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

I'm using it in three different contexts:

- When I retrieve a registered User
- When I'm editing some user's data
- When I'm including a new user

When I'm creating a new User, the property 'id' will not be present in the object.  In both other cases, this property 'id' must be present.

I've solved this problem using the following definition:

```
type UserType = {
  id?: number;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

I'm new to Typescript. In in terms of best practices, should I create a different type for editing and creating? Is it OK to define the 'id' property as optional in this case?

Comment: Setting `id` as optional and sharing the type is not the best approach here since that would mean that the `id` could be omitted in methods where you would expect it to be required. Using either a separate type, a derived type or etc would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this a best practice but you can also use utility type [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to *constructs a type by picking all properties from `Type` and then removing `Keys`*

```
type RegisteredUser = {
    id: number;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

type UnRegisteredUser = Omit<RegisteredUser, "id">
```

So you can use `RegisteredUser` type in the context of *When I retrieve a registered User* or  *When I'm editing some user's data* and `UnRegisteredUser` in the context of *When I'm including a new user*.